# Microsoft Edge turning site into responsive

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, responsive

I have a site I've built that has basic responsive media queries in it for certain small width browsers. Nothing fancy. I am seeing in a 1500px + wide monitor, when I view the site in Edge it triggers my media queries - as if I am viewing the site on a mobile phone. In every other browser the media queries work fine.

I am curious if anyone has come across this before in their own projects, or if I have a special bug only showing up in Edge. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turn off emulation? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/emulation/

Comment: this problem is happening to all users viewing the site, not just developers.

Comment: Please include a demo of your code that reproduces the issue, either using a Stack Snippet here or by using a coding sandbox site like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It might be a stupid suggestion, but is there a missing semicon inside your CSS? Ain't there a CSS Lint tool to validate your CSS?